# Grammatik in »Russisch Brot«

Tags: adjective-ending, brand-name

Um welche Erscheinung handelt es sich beim grammatikalisch falschen Produktnamen *Russisch Brot*?

1. Um die künstlerische Freiheit?
2. Um eine historisch falsche Übersetzung, die sich eingebürgert hat?
3. Um ein Deppenleerzeichen?

Comment: Weiteres Beispiel übrigens: Kölnisch Wasser.

Comment: Die beiden Antworten hier sagen aus, dass es sich um eine historisch entstandene Redewendung handelt. Ist das nicht genau das, was der Fragesteller mit Erklärung 2 meinte?

Comment: Mit "historisch falsch" bin ich allerdings nicht einverstanden.

Comment: Richtig. "Historisch richtig" wäre richtig ;)

Comment: Russisch Roulette, Russisch Ei, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nichts davon.

[image]

Duden "Handbuch der deutschen Grammatik" sagt dazu:

> Das attributive Adjektiv tritt im Deutschen [...] vor sein Bezugssubstantiv [...] und richtet sich in Kasus, Genus und Numerus nach ihm. Allerdings treten auch unflektierte Adjektive in attributiver Funktion auf. Sie kommen vor allem in feststehenden Wendungen vor, sind als solche überliefert und spiegeln Regeln einer nicht mehr aktuellen Grammatik wider.

(Über die spezifischen "Regeln der nicht mehr aktuellen Grammatik" lässt man sich leider nicht genauer aus, sie wären aber hier interessant zu wissen)

Als Beispiele werden genannt:

- Russisch Brot (Aha)
- jung Siegfried
- halb Frankreich

Es handelt sich also um einen (bei *Russisch Brot*) Fachbegriff, der sich wahrscheinlich durch relativ seltene Verwendung diese altertümliche (Nicht-)Deklination erhalten hat.

Eigenes Beispiel, in dem das Adjektiv zu "Brot" auch nicht dekliniert wird, ebenfalls eine feststehende Wendung:

> Trocken Brot macht Wangen rot

Answer (score 3):

In early New High German (notably in Luther’s writings) it is very common to omit the inflectional endings of adjectives, and even of the article, e.g. in the well-known hymn “Ein feste Burg ist unser Gott”, where in modern German you would have to say “Eine feste Burg...” The uninflected attributive adjective survives in certain fixed expressions, especially in proverbs, e.g. “Gut Ding braucht Weile”. It has a decidedly archaic feel.